# HTML audio player track links opening in new browser

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am trying to create an HTML audio player and have everything functioning so far. The only problem is that when a track in the playlist is clicked, the mp3 is loaded in a new browser window.

When they play button is clicked (for the currently selected track) it plays in the audio player, which is what I would like to happen for all tracks in the playlist when clicked on.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

https://jsfiddle.net/47qh28c6/

The HTML

```
<audio id="audio" preload="auto" tabindex="0" controls="" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source type="audio/mp3" src="http://www.archive.org/download/bolero_69/Bolero.mp3">
    Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
</audio>
<ul id="playlist">
    <img style="float:right;width:150px;" src="images/placer.gif">
    <li class="active"><a href="http://www.archive.org/download/bolero_69/Bolero.mp3">Ravel Bolero</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.archive.org/download/MoonlightSonata_755/Beethoven-MoonlightSonata.mp3">Moonlight Sonata - Beethoven</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.archive.org/download/CanonInD_261/CanoninD.mp3">Canon in D Pachabel</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.archive.org/download/PatrikbkarlChamberSymph/PatrikbkarlChamberSymph_vbr_mp3.zip">patrikbkarl chamber symph</a></li>

</ul>
```

And the Javascript

```
var audio;
var playlist;
var tracks;
var current;

init();
function init(){
current = 0;
audio = $('audio');
playlist = $('#playlist');
tracks = playlist.find('li a');
len = tracks.length - 1;
audio[0].volume = .10;
audio[0].play();
playlist.find('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    link = $(this);
    current = link.parent().index();
    run(link, audio[0]);
});
audio[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e){
    current++;
    if(current == len){
        current = 0;
        link = playlist.find('a')[0];
    }else{
        link = playlist.find('a')[current];    
    }
    run($(link),audio[0]);
});
}
function run(link, player){
    player.src = link.attr('href');
    par = link.parent();
    par.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    audio[0].load();
    audio[0].play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct. The only issue that I found with the [JSFiddle that you shared in the question](https://jsfiddle.net/47qh28c6/), and the one that is causing all the trouble in the JSFiddle, is that you are not including the jQuery library.

As you are not adding the library, the `init()` function will throw an error when it reaches the code `audio = $('audio')`:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

and it will stop executing the rest of the code in the function, so the code that affect the behavior of the `a`s inside the playlist will not be executed, and the normal behavior (opening the link) will not be modified.

Once you add the jQuery library to the JSFiddle, the player seems to be working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/47qh28c6/3/.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say that I DO have jquery included in the head of my HTML file, but it still seems to open tracks in a new browser window

Comment: Do you get any error in the console? I cannot reproduce that behavior once jQuery is added to the JSFiddle